# basic as3 grammar/errors

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

```
    package
    {
include flash.events.* //1084: Syntax error: expecting stringliteral before flash.
include flash.ui.*

public class tank () //1068: Unable to open included file: /Volumes/scottthreet/Documents/FLASH/tankdrive/leftbrace. 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before leftbrace.
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyBoardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyBoardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp);

    var keys:Array = []; 

    function update(e:Event):void
    {
        var rotang:Int = 0;
        var speed:Int;
        if(keys[Key.I])
        {
            rotang = rotang + 1;
        }
        if(keys[Key.J])
        {
            rotang = rotang - 1;
        }
        if(keys[Key.W])
        {
            rotang = rotang - 1; 
        }
        if(speed > 0)
        {
            speed = speed - 1;
        }
        if(speed < 0)
        {
            speed = speed + 1;
        }
        if(keys[Key.S])
        {
            rotang = rotang + 1;
        }
        if(keys[Key.I] && keys[Key.W])
        {
            speed = speed + 3;
        }
        if(keys[Key.K] && keys[Key.S])
        {
            speed = speed - 3;
        }
        if(speed > 30)
        {
            speed = 30;
        }
        if(speed < -30)
        {
            speed = -30;
        }
        public function degreesToRadians(param1:Number) : Number
        {
            return param1 * Math.PI / 180;
        }
        this.vy +=  Math.sin(this.degreesToRadians(rotang)) *speed;
        this.vx += Math.cos(this.degreesToRadians(rotang))*speed;
        this.y = tank.y + tank.vy;
        this.x = tank.x + tank.vx;
        this.rotation = rotang * Math.PI / 180;
    }

    function onKeyDown(e:Event):void
    {
        keys[e.keyCode] = true;
    }

    function onKeyUp(e:Event):void
    {
        keys[e.keyCode] = false;
    }

}
    }
```

Comments are where i got errors and I don't understand what is wrong with it... I have found nothing by googling those errors, just other forms of the errors...

Anyone have some basic example as3 code? For some reason it wants me to add details; not many details to add...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check your code is in a class(.as), or fla. ActionScript 3.0 class-based, and script-based language. in .fla is only available script. you ever written in fla? if right you must be written in .as

As3 Class include syntax is not `include`, but `import`

`include flash.events.*` -> `import flash.events.*`

In Class your `function()` syntax will be scoped to the default namespace: internal. It will not be visible outside of this package. Settings to suit your function purpose.

`function bar();` means `internal function bar();`

> - **public** access modifier allows every Class access
> - **internal** access modifier allows Classes sharing this package access
> - **protected** access modifier allows subclasses access
> - **private** access modifier allows no external access

And constructor is must same .as filename as follow:

// MyClass.as

```
package 
{
  import flash.display.Sprite;
  public class MyClass extends Sprite 
  {
       public function MyClass() 
       {

       }
  }
}
```

And here is Sample Class Ball.

//Ball.as

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Ball extends Sprite
    {
        private var _color:uint;
        private var _radius:Number;
        private var _vx:Number = 0;
        private var _vy:Number = 0;

        public function Ball(radius:Number, color:uint = 0xffffff)
        {
            _radius = radius;
            _color = color;
            draw();
        }

        private function draw():void
        {
            graphics.clear();
            graphics.lineStyle(0);
            graphics.beginFill(_color, 1);
            graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, _radius);
            graphics.endFill();
            graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 1);
        }

        public function update():void
        {
            x += _vx;
            y += _vy;
        }

        public function set color(value:uint):void
        {
            _color = value;
            draw();
        }

        public function get color():uint
        {
            return _color;
        }

        public function set radius(value:Number):void
        {
            _radius = value;
            draw();
        }

        public function get radius():Number
        {
            return _radius;
        }

        public function set vx(value:Number):void
        {
            _vx = value;
        }

        public function get vx():Number
        {
            return _vx;
        }

        public function set vy(value:Number):void
        {
            _vy = value;
        }

        public function get vy():Number
        {
            return _vy;
        }

    }
}
```

If you want using a in Flash, your .fla file and Ball.as file located same directory.

And run this script

```
var ball:Ball = new Ball(10,0x0000ff);
addChild(ball);
```

If you want using a in Flash Builder, Ball.as file located same your src folder.

And build this Class. If you make a Project, automatically is created same name Class. ex) MyClass

//MyClass.as

```
package {

    import flash.display.Sprite;

        public class MyClass extends Sprite
        {
            public function MyClass() 
            {

                var ball:Ball = new Ball(10,0xff0000);
                ball.x = 10;
                ball.y = 10;
                addChild(ball);
            } 

        }
}
```

`package blah.blah { }` mean your working directory or documents src relative path. for example, `import flash.display.Sprite` is packed as follows syntax: `package flash.display.sprite`. In Flash, maybe also Flash builder ActionScript 3.0 common class already have been set. already have been linking, So it's available from any folder, we will. if you want this setting check, see a `File-ActionScript Settings - Library path`. the default path as follows: `$(AppConfig)/ActionScript 3.0/libs.`

Comment: Thanks; after reading it is this a decent shortened version: "use public before classes and import != include"? Also whats up with the whole package thing? EDIT: Public = global?

Comment: Oh; didn't realize it last night but thanks for the basic grammar code stuff, If i come up with these annoying errors again I will check this first.